# Browse server files with VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

I have just finished installing OpenVPN on my CentOS 7 server, and I have connected successfully. 
I checked my public IP address, and it's the remote server IP.

But I still can't browse the folders on that server from my Windows client.
I think I need to activate some sharing things or change the workgroup or change some setting, but I don't know.

So I'm here asking for help: **How can I access network resources over a VPN?**

I don't want to use Samba because I believe it's possible to do it without.

I'm using the OpenVPN web interface

[image: OpenVPN Screenshot]

### Added info

`/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
# System default settings live in /usr/lib/sysctl.d/00-system.conf.
# To override those settings, enter new settings here, or in an /etc/sysctl.d/<name>.conf file
#
# For more information, see sysctl.conf(5) and sysctl.d(5).

# Added By Me

# Recycle Zombie connections 
net.inet.tcp.fast_finwait2_recycle=1 
net.inet.tcp.maxtcptw=200000 

# Increase number of files 
kern.maxfiles=65535 
kern.maxfilesperproc=16384 

# Increase page share factor per process 
vm.pmap.pv_entry_max=54272521 
vm.pmap.shpgperproc=20000 

# Increase number of connections 
vfs.vmiodirenable=1 
kern.ipc.somaxconn=3240000 
net.inet.tcp.rfc1323=1 
net.inet.tcp.delayed_ack=0 
net.inet.tcp.restrict_rst=1 
kern.ipc.maxsockbuf=2097152 
kern.ipc.shmmax=268435456 

# Host cache 
net.inet.tcp.hostcache.hashsize=4096 
net.inet.tcp.hostcache.cachelimit=131072 
net.inet.tcp.hostcache.bucketlimit=120 

# Increase number of ports 
net.inet.ip.portrange.first=2000 
net.inet.ip.portrange.last=100000 
net.inet.ip.portrange.hifirst=2000 
net.inet.ip.portrange.hilast=100000 
kern.ipc.semvmx=131068 

# Disable Ping-flood attacks 
net.inet.tcp.msl=2000 
net.inet.icmp.bmcastecho=1 
net.inet.icmp.icmplim=1 
net.inet.tcp.blackhole=2 
net.inet.udp.blackhole=1

# Mysql conf
```

Comment: Sorry Oldmud0 I gave Too mush work :p I hope u won't have more in this comment :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're misunderstanding that Windows can't natively just "browse" a Linux filesystem, and when networking is involved you need a protocol so that the two devices can communicate with each other using the same language.

Honestly, you are best off installing either of the following:

**Samba** - so that you can create some read/write shares on your Centos 7 box and then you can natively connect to the shares through Windows. You need to configure the shares/folders that can be accessed but you can't view the whole Centos filesystem (i.e. being able to view everything under `/`). Well, you can, but it would be the most stupid idea. Additionally, Samba allows  you to open remote files by double-clicking and the local associated application will open the file to allow for editing/saving back to the remote location.

OR

**SSH server** - If you install an SSH server on your Centos box then you can use a client such as WinSCP on your Windows box and (depending on what account you log on to the remote server with) access the remote filesystem. WinSCP works best if you download the remote file to a local folder and then open the file (it does this anyway) and it can only natively open text files. Binary files are a bit more complicated.

Comment: Hmmm nice Explenation Thanks, so i dont need vpn for thsi task !!

i can just use samba or ssh server.

Comment: This is a very misleading explanation. The OP is about **how can i Access Network Resources Over a VPN**. So one must asusme that network resources are already in place, and that somehow VPN clients have no access to them. Normally, this occurs because of routing problems, or because some services (Samba, but also any UPnP) only reply to queries from within their LAN. My answer addresses both problems, yours neither.

Comment: My understanding is that the OP has a remote Centos box (as I do) and they're trying to access the file system (as I do) - for example to view website source files or remote backup files. I use WinSCP because I have installed and enabled SSH server. If I wanted to, though, I could install Samba and OpenVPN, VPN in and open folders I'd configured in the Samba config file... My answer probably doesn't explain the differences but I'm sure the OP is trying to simply find a way to access a Linux box such as a VPS...?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following line

```
 push "route 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0"
```

to your server's configuration file, having assumed that `192.168.0.0/24` is your home network, otherwise change accordingly.

Also, you need to `masquerade` the clients' addresses as follows:

```
 iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/24 -d 192.168.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
```

where I assumed you use the network `10.0.0.0/24` for the OpenVPN tunnel, and again that `192.168.0.0/24` is your home LAN.

You must also make sure that IPv4 forwarding is enabled in `/etc/sysctl.conf`, and that no `iptables` rules blocks forwarding between the virtual interface (`tun0/tap0`) and the LAN interface.

Comment: I added up the content of sysctl.conf can u see if i have IPv4 forwarding is enabled ? 
And this push configuration should i add in the vpn conf or linux conf ?
And i have FIRWALLD not iptable.
Thanks

Comment: @Resurectionx In that file there is no IPv4 forwarding. You should search for a line like this `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` inside **any** of the files `/etc/sysctl.d`.

Comment: Ok i added it but i wont be able to manage linux ressources with windows as Big Chris said.
So thanks anyway

Comment: I am not sure I understand. If you have Samba shares on the server, you will need Samba to access them from the OpenVPN client. But the Samba server is designed to reply to queries **only within its own LAN**, thus you will need the MASQUERADE to make the VPN clients `appear as though they belong to the LAN`.  Using Samba **alone** will not work, you need the MASQUERADING.

Comment: Ok i got it i was thinking that samba work in remote without using a vpn :p